# Securing seashell to an open painted wall

Tags: adhesives, decoupage-glue

I would like to place a variety of different shaped seashell on a wall space in my bathroom. Is gluing them to the wall the best option? If so, what type of glue. Keeping in mind this is a wall in my bathroom. And should humidity be a concern

Comment: Hi Anthony, do the answers provided in the following question or any of the questions linked to that post (to the right, under 'Linked') give you a solution to your problem? [What kind of glue works for stones and shells?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/542/)